# Interpreting a thermodynamics equation using a picture

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, ideal-gas, isotherm

Given
$$ \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial p}\Bigg|_{t} =\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial p}\Bigg|_{v}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial p}\Bigg|_{t}\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial v}\Bigg|_{p} \tag{1}$$
where
\begin{gather}
\Gamma(p,v) = vp^{2}\tag{2a}\\
pv=t\tag{2b}
\end{gather}
I'm trying to interpret $(1)$ using words or preferably a picture.
Note for notations: $p$ is pressure; $v$ is volume; and $t$ is temperature.

$(2 \text{b})$ is equivalent to the *ideal gas law* but with temperature in units of energy. I suspect the picture we're looking after is something along the sides of a $pv$ diagram involving an isotherm. Since $t$ is held constant in this setting, my conclusion is that $(1)$ represents the isothermal compression of an ideal gas, but frankly this conclusion is shaky and I'm not sure of my interpretation.

Comment: Do your $PVT$ in the text represent $pvt$ in the equations?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne  yes I believe they do.

Comment: See my latest post on the other site.